# sharepoint.stackexchange data analysis - 2017

Tags: discussion

A year ago I've created some analysis of data in sharepoint.stackexchange. This year I decided to do same and compare some graphics to 2016.

**Here the link** - [SharePoint development state in 2017: story based on sharepoint.stackexchange analysis with Power BI](http://spblog.net/post/2018/01/18/SharePoint-development-state-in-2017-story-based-on-sharepointstackexchange-analysis-with-Power-BI)

Please enjoy :)

Comment: Great efforts, i am impressed by your work...I just started my PowerBi project so i will use your stuff as an example. Again thank you for Sharing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your awesome effort to share these great statistics with us :) I really enjoyed reading your wonderful and structured report. Thanks again @Sergei Sergeev for sharing this featured post :). I just have a bit note in the Tops section, although the report title is **SharePoint development state in 2017** it shows the *Tops* at all time, not the *Tops* stats in **2017**! Can I get this information through the Power BI report?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP I've updated the post and added a link to the archive with actual report with data, so you can download and see it locally. I really enjoyed with Power BI, unfortunately I don't have projects which involve using Power BI, that's why I only play with it from time to time.

Comment: @MohamedEl-QassasMVP actually it is difficult to show many stats on TOPs by specific year, simply because exchange API doesn't provide much historic information. Only two types of reports can be build to show info for 2017 - TOP by rating (however you can do the same in sharepoint.stackexchange `/users` page) and TOP by count of answers (because API stores creation date of the answer).